# Effect on change in estimated value on Percent Error

Tags: statistics

Here is how i calculate the percent of error `(Estimated - Actual)/Actual * 100` where the estimated value is obtained by subtracting two different numbers; let us say n1 and n2, so percent of error formula becomes `(n1-n2)-Actual/Actual * 100`. Now am trying to figure out how much difference does it make to the `percent of error` if i don't include 4% of n2 in the above equation, considering value of n2 is roughly 3% of n1. Would highly appreciate if anyone can provide some inputs on the same.